# Getting each image in custom WYSIWYG field - Advanced Custom Fields plugin - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Custom Post UI and Advanced Custom Fields plugin, One of my custom fields is a WYSIWYG field for uploading images (attached to a 'Project' custom post type).I would then like to get the images I uploaded to this WYSIWYG field one by one. Using echo get_field ('name of field') doesnt work because it returns all the images at once.l tried using

'attachment', 'post_per_page' => '-1', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_parent' => $post-> ID ); ?>  ID ); ?>"

This also doesnt work as it returns all images attached to the post even those not in the WYSIWYG field i'm trying to target although in thumbnail sizes.

Note, I have other images attached to this same post but i just want images from a specific WYSIWYG field in the post. I'm actually trying to create an image swap gallery with the thumbnails as navigation so I created a wysiwyg field where the user can upload thumbnail images.I'm trying to use the ultimate image swap gallery used here - http://bit.ly/10eyycX 
Sorry for the long post.Looking forward to any help I can get, I've been on this for weeks...

Comment: You can use "echo get_field('field name');" function. It returns you the content of ACF custom field.

Comment: @Pranita thanks for your response but that outputs all the images i uploaded in the WYSIWYG editor,but what i need is each image 1 after the other